# I have question about python for loop if statement and multiple for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So if I get input number "n" and what I want to do is print 1~n like this. If n = 10

```
1

23

456

78910
```

and my code is this

```
x = int(input())
n=1
for i in range(1, x+1):
    sum = (n+1)*n // 2
    print(i , end = ' ')
    if(sum == i):
        print()
        n+=1
```

I solved this question with my TA but is there a way to solve using multiple for statements other than this one? I don't want to use `sum = (n+1)*n // 2` this part because my TA actually made this part without explanation.

Comment: Btw, the `(n + 1) * n / 2` is a known mathematical shortcut that can be used in place of a summation of an integer spanning across the range `1...n`, but I have long since forgotten the name of the person who had figured that out.

Comment: @xxh - That would be Gauss.

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with mathematics and proofs, but you can prove that the sum of consecutive integers 1+2+3 +...+n = n(n + 1)/2 with a proof by induction. This is well documented online as it's probably the simplest proof by induction. You may be more comfortable using it, if you understand the proof.

Comment: @xxh - but, is there a way to solve it by using multiple for statements without using that Gauss's method? I want to solve it without using a mathematical formula...

Comment: you can sum all numbers up to n in a for loop but the trade off is that it is O(n) time to do this, opposed to O(1) time to use Gauss sum, so using a for loop for summing is less efficient.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, sounds about right, Gauss' sum, it's the most efficient way to solve this, much more compact and efficient, but if OP is really insistent, then they could use the double range based loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you were thinking about:

```
x = int(input())
n = 1
for i in range(1, x+1):
    for j in range(1, i):
        if n <= x:
            print(n, end=' ')
        n += 1
    print()
    if n >= x:
        break
```

If you're worried about needlessly looping too often on `j` for very large `x`, you could change:

```
        if n <= x:
            print(n, end=' ')
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Wow, you are a greater person to me than Gauss. Thank you so much, genius...

Comment: I can only recommend you study the code in detail and try to understand what it is you missed - it helps to step through the code line by line, keeping track of the values of the various variables. Please accept the answer with the check mark, if it answers your question fully.

Comment: I am currently learning your code line by line. Thank you very much. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

of course you can do the summation using another for loop

```
sum = 0
for j in range(1,n+1):
    sum += j
```

you cold also do `sum = sum(range(n+1))`, but `(n + 1) * n // 2` is the best way of getting the summation of n